# listview not clickable and search in the list

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, search

When I click on any item in list view it must move me to another list contain cars model for the same car type but the list wouldn't to be clickable.

and the search (edit text (inputSearch) wouldn't to filter the values.

---

custom adapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String[] Type;
int[] Img;
Context mContext;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] carType, int[] carImg) {
    super(context, R.layout.cars_type_res);
    this.Type = carType;
    this.Img = carImg;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Type.length;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cars_type_res, parent, false);
        mViewHolder.cImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_car_type);
        mViewHolder.cType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_car_type);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    }else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
        mViewHolder.cImg.setImageResource(Img[position]);
        mViewHolder.cType.setText(Type[position]);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView cImg;
    TextView cType;
}}
```

---

CarType class

```
public class CarType extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

public CarType() {

}

private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
EditText inputSearch;
ListView listView;
View view;
String[] carType = {"Alfaromeo", "ASTONMARTIN", "Audi", "Bentley", "BMW", "Bugatti",
        "Cadillac", "CHERY", "Chevrolet", "CITROEN", "Dodge", "Ferrari", "FIAT", "Ford", "GMC",
        "Honda", "HUMMER", "Hyundai", "Infiniti", "ISUZU", "Jaguar", "JEEP", "KIA", "Land Rover",
        "Lexus", "Lincoln", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Mercedes", "MINI", "Mitsubishi", "Nissan", "Opel",
        "PEUGEOT", "RENAULT", "SEAT", "SUBARU", "TOYOTA", "VOLKSWAGEN", "VOLVO"};

int[] carImg = {R.drawable.alfaromeo, R.drawable.aston_martin, R.drawable.audi,
        R.drawable.bentely,
        R.drawable.bmw, R.drawable.bugatti, R.drawable.cadillac, R.drawable.chery,
        R.drawable.chevrolet,
        R.drawable.citroen, R.drawable.dodge, R.drawable.ferrari, R.drawable.fiat,
        R.drawable.ford,
        R.drawable.gmc, R.drawable.honda, R.drawable.hummer, R.drawable.hyundai,
        R.drawable.infiniti,
        R.drawable.isuzu, R.drawable.jaguar, R.drawable.jeep, R.drawable.kia,
        R.drawable.land_rover,
        R.drawable.lexus, R.drawable.lincoln, R.drawable.maserati, R.drawable.mazda,
        R.drawable.mercedes,
        R.drawable.mini, R.drawable.mitsubishi, R.drawable.nissan, R.drawable.opel,
        R.drawable.peugeot,
        R.drawable.renault, R.drawable.seat, R.drawable.subaru, R.drawable.toyota,
        R.drawable.volkswagen, R.drawable.volvo
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_car_type, container, false);

    inputSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.car_list_view);

    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), carType, carImg);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), carType[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String txt = inputSearch.getText().toString();
            (CarType.this).customAdapter.getFilter().filter(txt);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    });

    return view;

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}}
```

how i can make listview clickable in this code?.

how i can make search function working in this code?.

Any suggestions would be welcomed

Help me please.

Comment: Please, at least add some question to your post. You're not asking anything as it is right now.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov i edit my post :)

Comment: For clickable `ListView` implement `ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` method.

Comment: @Stanojkovic I mplemented ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() method but its not working